# Sending mail from server to own domain, mail hosted in google apps and Windows Live

Tags: sendmail, debian-squeeze

I have several domains hosted in my web server, most of them have mail working with Google Apps, however, since Google Apps has no free accounts any more I am now using Windows Live services with my new domains.

Lets state domiain1.com works with Google Apps and domain2.com works with Windows Live.

My original config used the MAIL_HUB and LOCAL_RELAY like this:

```
define(`MAIL_HUB', `domain1.com.')dnl
define(`LOCAL_RELAY', `domain1.com.')dnl
```

I tried adding the domain2.com but it didn't work. Then I found that i could try and find the mx records with some code:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
Kbestmx bestmx -T.TMP
LOCAL_RULE_0
R $* < @ domain1.com. > $*       $#esmtp $@ [$(bestmx domain1.com. $)] $: $1 < @ domain1.com. > $2
```

It seems that this code states that the domain1.com MX records are the ones for Google, if I add the domain2.com it tries to reach Google instead of Windows.

How can I state that domain1.com MX records are from Google and domain2.com MX records are from Windows Live?

I am runnin Debian 6, my local-host-names file just has localhost stated in it.

Comment: Is `domain2.com` listed on sendmail list of local email domains? To get list of local email domains execute as root the following command: `echo '$=w' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -bt`

Comment: 1) Sendmail by default adds automatically some names to the list of local email domains 2) What is reported by the following test commands executed by root? `sendmail -br x@domain2.com`

Comment: Thank you Andrzej. Domain2.com is not listed in the local email domains, here's the output:

     root@server:~# echo '$=w' | /usr/sbin/sendmail -bt
     ADDRESS TEST MODE (ruleset 3 NOT automatically invoked)
     Enter <ruleset> <address>
     > domain1.com
     DO1
     localhost.localdomain
     subdomain.domain1.com
     localhost
     [localhost.localdomain]
     [127.0.0.1]
     [subdomain.domain1.com]
     [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
     [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
     [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]

Comment: The second comand doesn't let me use -r and it says:

     root@server:~# sendmail -b 'marcozink@domain2.com'
     Recipient names must be specified

I think it's important to say that my server does not host email, I just want to send mail with php from my sites, this works as long as the mail is not sent to domain2.com

Comment: It should be `sendmail -bv x@domain2.com`. The LOCAL_RULE_0 path you have mentioned seems to be required only for domains listed as local email domains.

Comment: Ok, The command outputs this: X@domain2.com... deliverable: mailer esmtp, host domain2.com., user x@domain2.com. If LOCAL_RULE_0 is for local e-mails, should I add it? How should I do that?

Comment: The domains you want to use in LOCAL_RULE_0, need to be in $=w. The easiest way for this is to include them in /etc/mail/local-host-names and restart sendmail.

Comment: I just added the domain2 and domain1 to the lis of local-host-names I see now there is some change in the steps during the sendmail but it still does not get where it should http://pastebin.com/nEqMRs7T

Comment: I've been looking at the output, it seems live is blocking my IP, do you know a way to get around this? Thanks again Andrzej!

Comment: It looks that it's working now, thank you very much Andrzej and adamo.